# unable to access rest CXF with org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, cxf

i am trying to create a rest service and client using CXF 3.1.2 as below,

**Service method declaration:**

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes({"application/xml", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @Path("/agentLogout")
    public JSONObject agentLogout(String ext) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();//org.json.simple.JSONObject
    obj.put("DN", ext);
    return obj;
    }
```

**Client Code:**

```
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(REST_URI); // REST_URI is configured correctly 
    client.path("agentLogout").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    Response agentLogoutResponse = client.post("10245");
    System.out.println(agentLogoutResponse.readEntity(JSONObject.class));//org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

When i run the client code i am getting the below exception,

**In Service side :**

```
        Nov 05, 2015 3:07:08 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
    WARNING: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 406 Not Acceptable
```

**In Client side :**

```
    Nov 05, 2015 3:07:08 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils logMessageHandlerProblem
    SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class org.json.simple.JSONObject, ContentType: */*
    Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: No message body reader has been found for class org.json.simple.JSONObject, ContentType: */*
```

Can you please correct me here and also may i know the right way to use Json in CXF rest web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WS produces `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` :

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

and your client expects `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` :

```
client.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```

This is the reason of "*HTTP 406 Not Acceptable*".

Change your client to accept JSON or you server to produce Text.

---

Moreover, you don't need to return a `JSONObject` from your methods. Just return a model object.

Returning a `JSONObject` will complicates things because it will return the JSON representation of the `JSONObject` which is not equivalent to the JSON representation of the object contained in the `JSONObject`.

And you could get the error "*No message body reader has been found for class org.json.simple.JSONObject*" because CXF doesn't know how to represent a `JSONObject` in JSON.

In your case you could return a `Map<String,String>` with one entry : key = "DN", value = "3254".

Comment: Thanks and as per your comment i have changed my code as below, could you let me know whether it is right way?